# Regex Multiple email validation

Tags: regex, email-validation

I Want to implement multiple email validation with specific domain using regex separated by `;`. Requirement is to allow only two email id separated by semicolon.
I tried regex

`^([\w+-.%]+@domain+\.com[~]?){1,2}$`

it works fine but it validates email followed by `;` . It should work as below

1) `abc@domain.com` valid

2) `abc@domain.com;abc1@domain.com` valid

3) `abc@domain.com;`  invalid

4) `abc@domain.com;abc1@domain.com;`  invalid

How to do it using regex?

Comment: Try `^[\w+.%-]+@domain\.com(?:;[\w+.%-]+@domain\.com)?$`

Comment: Perfect. It's working as expected .Thanks a lot Wiktor

Comment: However, you did not indicate the environment. Probably, you need to declare the regex in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
"^([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com)(;([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com))?$"
```

It consists of *addres 1*

`([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com)`

and *zero* or *one* further addres

`(;([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com))?`

`"^...$"` makes shure that there are no other characters around.

*Group 1* and *Group 3* will contain the addresses

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/D7P5TC/1)

Comment: Your regex allows [`ab,,,,,,,c@domain.com;ab,,,,,c1@domain.com`](https://regex101.com/r/D7P5TC/2). Not sure it is expected.

Comment: Thank's! You're right the `-`belongs to the end of the `[...]`

Comment: Yeah, just what I suggest. Actually, you may put the hyphen at the start of the character class, too.

Comment: Or use a backslash... `\-` :)

Comment: No, escaping is not always a good idea. It won't work in POSIX and in C++ `std::regex` with ECMAScript flavor.

Comment: If it is for VB.NET, then your `"^([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com)(;([\w+.%-]+?@domain\.com))?$"` will work. It makes no sense discussing it, OP did not indicate the flavor.